# Set value of angular material select autocomplete programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple [angular material autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) function. Now i want to set the value / selected option of this autocomplete programmatically. This is my code:

**hardware.component.html**

```
<tr>
    <td class="desc pd7">Firmware</td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group mb0">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Select firmware" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControlFirmware" [matAutocomplete]="auto1" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFirmwares">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let firmware of filteredFirmwares | async" [value]="firmware" (onSelectionChange)="getIdFromFirmware($event, firmware)">
                        {{ firmware.name }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**hardware.component.ts**

```
this.miscellaneousTerminalService.getMiscellaneous('firmware').subscribe(data => {
    if(data.success) {
        this.availableFirmwares = data.data;
        this.filteredFirmwares = this.myControlFirmware.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(valFirmware => this.filterFirmwares(valFirmware))
        );
    }
});

filterFirmwares(valFirmware: any): any[] {
    return this.availableFirmwares.filter(firmware => {
        let name = valFirmware.name ? valFirmware.name : valFirmware;
        return firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
}

displayFirmwares(firmware: any): string {
    return firmware ? firmware.name : firmware;
}

getIdFromFirmware(event, firmware) {
    if(event.isUserInput) {
        this.selectedFirmware = firmware._id;

    }
}
```

i tried to set my firmware model to the `_id` of the selected Firmware or the name, but nothing works. How can i set the value programmatically. I'm using Angular Material @V 7

Comment: So basically you want to set the value of the `input` to a specific option? Like a default value when the component is rendered?

Comment: when using a displayFunction for each value, the value you're trying to set programmatically will also be piped through your displayFunction. So, transform your value to fit or make sure the displayFunction can handle whatever value you set. Details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63254063/504075

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish this.

If you aren't sure of the options ahead of time, you retrieve them from API for example, you can get them from the `MatAutocompleteTrigger` like this.

```
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material'

@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) _auto: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

let options = this._auto.autocomplete.options.toArray()
```

This stackblitz sets the value to `two` when the button is clicked. I retrieve the options from the trigger and use the array of options to set the value in the `formControl`... in your case it would be `this.myControlFirmware.setValue(options[1].value)`

```
 setValue() {
    let options = this._auto.autocomplete.options.toArray()
    this.myControl.setValue(options[1].value)
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3gn1w?embed=1&file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts

Comment: How can I set the value programmatically if this value is not contained in the options list?

Comment: I did, but the `optionSelected` event is not triggered. How can I trigger it?

Comment: This is setting the value via the underlying `formControl`, it will not trigger the component events this way. Because this is programmatically setting a value via the `formControl` just call the function the `optionSelected` event would call in the next line... no need to use the `optionSelected` event.

Comment: Another answer if you are looking `setValue` with an object in `mat-autocomplete`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454350/angular-material-autocomplete-prevents-reactive-from-setvalue-from-working