# angular material autocomplete prevents reactive from setValue from working

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, setvalue

Edit:
Resolved with Jojofoulk's comment.

when using the autocomplete components of angular-material,
I'm trying to use `setValue` to the input form, but its `[matAutocomplete]` attribute is preventing `setValue` from showing on the input.

Inspecting the reactive control reveals the value is right, and removing `[matAutocomplete]` makes it work,
but with it it's just not showing up.

```html
<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let skill of curObj.skills;index as ind">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" placeholder="choose skill" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="skill.control" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="optSel($event.option.value,skill)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of skill.filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</mat-list-item>
```

```
skill.control.setValue("some new value");
```

Comment: Why do you want some different value for the input and still want mat-autocomplete to be attached with that input.

Comment: Because I'm also changing it by code following outside actions.

Comment: It would be great if you provide the stackblitz for the same.

Comment: Assuming your `displayFn` is to display a certain property from an Object, are you making sure you are using `setValue()` to set the whole object object and not just the display value? The input should have the whole object when you couple it with the autoComplete using `[displayWith]`
Little example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjktt2

Comment: It worked!
Thanks man, good job!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `displayFn` takes the input to display it differently (usually a property of an object in your input), but it takes the whole object! You should make sure you are using `setValue()` to set an object and not just the value you want to display.

The input should hold the whole object when you couple it with the `[matAutoComplete]` using `[displayWith]`, the `displayFn` will take care of filling your input.

[Little example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjktt2)